# Absense of webelement throws exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please look at the script given below

```
<ul id="ul_list">
  <li>
     <a>Text1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <span>Text2</span>
   </li>
   <li>
     <span>Text3</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am able to find ul tag and Li tag.

```
WebElement ul_tag = wdriver.findElement(By.id("ul_list"));
List<WebElement li_tag = ul_tag.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
```

but the problem is when I iterate over "li_tag" I am trying to find span tag and in first attempt it throws exception (NoSuchElementFoundException). What I am suppose to do to avoid this case. for the time being I have handle it using try and catch block(Put continue in catch block so that the execution moves on). Is that the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: in the first li element it is 'a' tag and remaining are "span" tags. is it expected? can you share the code how you are iterating over all the li elements?

Answer (score 1):

For ignoring the "li" that does not have any span, rewrite the second line of your code like this:

```
List<WebElement> li_tag_with_span=ul_tag.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[descendant::span]"));
```

It finds all "li" that has "span" in its child nodes. Then you can iterate over the list.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to find span tag and in first attempt it throws exception (NoSuchElementFoundException)

As you're saying, you are looking for `<span>` element inside `<li>` but it throws exception at first attempt which is absolutely correct because inside first `<li>` element it's clearly looks no `<span>` element is present.

If you want to locate only `<span>` elements inside `<li>`, you can try using `cssSelector` in one liner solution instead as well as below :-

```
List<WebElement> span_tag = ul_tag.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#ul_list > li > span"));
```